# android:layout_width along with layout weight usage

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

why should i put `android:layout_width="0px"` when i use a`ndroid:layout_weight` property? For example following is my main.xml file , and in that i used `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`, and everything works fine, so why `android:layout_width="0px"` should be used when i am using the layout_weight property?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText" android:hint="enter your name"
        android:layout_weight="3"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is how my layout looks:
[image]

Comment: i wnated to know why must i use layout_width="0px" when i use layout weight property. i read it here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean) . In that see roetzi's comment.

Comment: Similar one.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly don't have to. Additionally `weight=0` doesn't make much sense. The `weight` parameter controls what part of the *remaining* space in the layout the widget occupies. So setting `width=0` effectively tells it to take up only the remaining space. If you set `width=30`, it will occupy 30 px|dp + all the remaining space. Setting 0 as the width makes it easier to get a predictable result on different screen sizes.

A common pattern is to have two widgets with `width=0` and equal weight to make them equally sized inside the parent container, where you don't care about the actual size (width or height).

Comment: weight=0 is perfectly fine in some cases

Answer (score 1):

Layout weight itself is used to give appropriate width as per weight property.
Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight)

> This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how
>   much space is should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value
>   allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view.

So eclipse suggests to give width as 0px

Answer (score 1):

**layout_weight you can specify a size ratio between multiple views.**

E.g. you have a Tabelview and a image which should show some additional information to the layout. The tabel should use 3/4 of the screen and image should use 1/4 of the screen. Then you will set the layout_weight of the tabelview to 3 and the layout_weight of the image to 1.

To get it work you also have to set the height or widthto 0px.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts